# chunking screen output using grep/head/awk/sed/etc

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have some output that prints an element every line. I want to be able to parse that output in chunks of N, even if the number of lines is not a multiple of N.

```
find . -f | chunk 10 1 # shows first chunk of size 10 
find . -f | chunk 10 2 # second chunk of size 10
find . -f | chunk 10 3 # last of size < n 
find . -f | chunk 10 4 # does nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chunk function can be implemented in bash as follows.

```
chunk(){
    size=$1
    n=$2

    firstline=$((n*size))
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt $firstline ]
    do
        read -r junk || return
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt $size ]
    do
        read -r str || return
        printf "%s\n" "$str"
        i=$((i+1))
    done
}
```

Note that results may be unexpected if files are added in between calls to `find`. So, you may want to implement a `save_chunks`/`get_chunk` API instead of your requested one, or do something like:

```
catn(){
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt $1 ] && read -r s
    do printf "%s\n" "$s";i=$((i+1))
    done
}
find -f . | 
    (catn 10; # shows first chunk of size 10 
     catn 10; # second chunk of size 10
     catn 10; # last of size < n 
     catn 10) # does nothing
```

This should also be faster.

Comment: Awesome. not sure how the series of head functions works though, it seems to just output the first chunk.

Comment: @barrrista Does the new catn function work for you?